# A single tick is drawn with a larger font when using twiny

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The MWE below comes from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981800/1391441) by [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell), stripped down to the bare minimum code needed to reproduce the issue.

The output of the MWE is this:

[image]

Notice how the `15` in the top x axis is larger than the rest of the tick values. As far as I can tell it has something to do with the combination of limits set for the `y` axis, the scatter plot, and the position of the ticks in the top `x` axis.

Is this a bug? How can I prevent this?

---

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# some random data.
b_x_axis = [0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4.]
t_x_axis = [45, 36, 30, 28, 25, 19, 15, 13, 9]
y = np.random.uniform(0., 10., 9)

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

for i in range(4):

    ax = plt.subplot(gs[i])
    ax2 = ax.twiny()

    # Set limit on x,y axis.
    ax.set_xlim(-0.5, max(b_x_axis)+0.5)
    plt.ylim(0., 230.)

    # Scatter plot.
    plt.scatter(b_x_axis, y)

    # Set font size for both x axis.
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), fontsize=8)
    ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_yticks(), fontsize=8)

    # Set range, ticks, and label for the second x axis.
    ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
    ax2.set_xticks(b_x_axis)
    ax2.set_xticklabels(t_x_axis)

plt.savefig('del.png', dpi=150)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line causes the issue:

```
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_yticks(), fontsize=8)
```

because it should be `ax2.get_xticks`, not `yticks`.
Anyway this line should be deleted all together, because the `xticklabels` are set again just 3 lines bellow. You can specify the fontsize there:

```
ax2.set_xticks(b_x_axis)
ax2.set_xticklabels(t_x_axis, fontsize=8)
```